# Does C# support a Time Based Event System?

Tags: c#, events, time, timer

I want to implement a real-time system in which events are triggered at known times.  I could use System.Timers.Timer, and at the end of each event calculate when the next event happens and go into a sleep mode until it occurs some milliseconds later.

The question is, is this the only option I have available or is there a way for events to Trigger after a known time, without starting hundreds of Timers?

The reason for the question is, while I expect each event to execute very quickly, it's possible that an event's start + duration will exceed the next event's start, and I don't want that.  Therefore, whatever you suggest has to be independent of the code that executes.

Comment: Have you already searched online for existing solutions? There are plenty of existing libraries out there written for .net like Quartz and HangFire.

Comment: From my feeling I would go for a custom-trigger with timers too. You wouldnt have to use hundreds of timers. What about one timer at a tick of 1000 which is comparing the current time against registred events from a list? And according your `start + duration` thing: Use background-workers for the execution, so the events will be processed on different threads!? Cant imagine any problems with that.

Comment: Windows Task Scheduler?

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/28760/custom-task-scheduler

Comment: @C4ud3x problem with waking up every second is that your process have to be active all the time (fine on desktop, more questionable everywhere else).

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee782519%28v=vs.110%29.aspx Tasks can handle what you need.

Comment: Real-time on .NET with GC? Are you joking?

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Ah I see, that makes sense.

Comment: Too all ... this is a real-time question where timing to the millisecond is crucial.  If the timing is out by as little as 10ms, the solution won't work.  As a result, suggestions like Quartz, HangFire, Windows Task Scheduler, is totally inadequate because managing to the millisecond is out of the question; and TaskFactory's Scheduler is a queuing system that only "ensures that the work takes place" but provides no ability to specify the timing of work.

Comment: C4ud3x is closer, but 1000ms is simply too coarse for real-time where millisecond timing is required.  It's the same reason why Martin's answer below won't work; timer would have to trigger every millisecond, and it would be seriously processor inefficient to implement any kind of event polling.

Comment: I think perhaps a pool of N timers might work, where the work is organized in a list ordered by it's event starting time.  When the timer pool starts or when it gets a timer to be recycled, it looks at the next unscheduled event to start and calculates a time in the future when the timer triggers the event.  When the event is triggered, the event fires and the timer is returned to the pool to be recycled.  This way if event A (start + execution > B start), we won't care because a different timer triggers B.  The only issue is making sure the pool has enough timers.

Comment: If Event A and Event B trigger at the same time, there will be two distinct events that trigger A & B, and B won't be serialized by A's executing time.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, Windows is not a [real time operating system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real-time_operating_system).

Secondly, the C# language running on .NET platform, which is a runtime with garbage collector.
A feature of the garbage collector is that occasionally it can cause stop-the-world. Such a pause can be very long, even tens of seconds (not milliseconds!)

Summing up, we can say that your task, where timing to the millisecond is crucial, is not feasible.

Comment: Huh? NYSE doesn't use an RTOS per semantic definition, but I can assure you, it definitely runs in real-time. FYI it runs on Red Hat Linux.

Comment: @code4life - Let's say it's possible, but it is more difficult. It depends on the needs of the author.

Comment: In early versions of C#, GC was a "stop the world" event, however it is no longer true as of 4.5. GC runs as a background thread and only needs to do a full pause when its under memory pressure. If you are seeing pauses in GC as much as 4 seconds, then you are doing something wrong in your code. Typically GC should complete in less than 50ms.

Comment: I'm just sayin'... :)   anyways the link you provided seemed more attuned towards embedded OSes, not PCs.

Comment: @code4life - NYSE uses a cluster of computers. At that time, when one goes to garbage collection, while others continue to operate. How to OP can achieve this on a single PC?

Comment: @RonBeyer - Yes you're right. But in comments OP wrote:  _this is a real-time question where timing to the millisecond is crucial_.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov: so basically, what you are saying is, the only true real-time OS is an RTOS, which in turn is an embedded system? So what next, we need to pop in these embedded boards into PCs to enjoy RT? Slightly confused...  :)

Comment: @code4life - I say: it depends on the requirements of the author.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, I don't expect to encounter GC in this system because objects aren't being created and disposed of ... rather events delegate references within a object.  You can also mitigate GC by controlling how frequently you construct/dispose objects; I encountered the processing impacts once when writing a cost calculation engine for a utility company.  Constructing and reusing an object vs. constructing and disposing objects was more than 20x faster.

Answer (score 0):

I doing it this way... I create a timer, and at each "tick", I check if I can execute the job. I don't know if it's the best way to do it, but it's working.

```
/// <summary>
    /// Indicate if the task is running
    /// </summary>
    private volatile bool _TaskIsRunning;

    /// <summary>
    /// Indicate if the task is running
    /// </summary>
    public bool TaskIsRunning
    {
        get { return _TaskIsRunning; }
        set { _TaskIsRunning = value; }
    }

public ClassConstructor()
{
TimerGetAndSendContent = new System.Timers.Timer();                
            TimerGetAndSendContent.Elapsed += Elapsed;
            TimerGetAndSendContent.Interval = Math.Ceiling(TsContent.TotalMilliseconds);
            TimerGetAndSendContent.Start();
}

public void Elapsed(Object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e))
{
if (!TaskIsRunning)
{
try
{
TaskIsRunning=true;

//Your code
}
finally
{
TaskIsRunning=false;
}
}
}
```

Comment: Where is any code for running this at a known time? How does it apply to the question?

Comment: Sorry, I did't specify that "Elapsed" is called by a timer.

Comment: From the question *"...is there a way for events to Trigger after a known time, **without starting hundreds of Timers**"*.

Comment: I don't understand... you use ONE timer, that tick every N seconds, I dont create MANY timers...
What's wrong with that?

Comment: I think what you posted is an incomplete thought, its not clear how you integrate a timer with the methods you've posted, you should try to make a complete example so its clear how you run N tasks using 1 timer given a time you want the task to run at.

Comment: Done! Hope it's clarify what I use.
I hope someone confirm me if it's the best way to do it, or give me a better exemple! :-)

Comment: Thanks Martin, but your idea won't work.  In my system you would have to trigger every millisecond, then there would be serious processor impacts to then implement some sort of event polling.